# Nextjs react: what is the div with the class selection_bubble_root for?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Nextjs, doing setup for a nextjs react project. I used create-next-app to initialize code base, then realized that there's a weird div tag with the class 'selection_bubble_root' right inside body. Its visibility is set to hidden but it still spares an annoying empty block.

[image]

Does anyone know about it? What is it for or how to remove it? Many thanks!!

Comment: i dont think is related to next.js, did you installed some other modules?

Comment: Nope, its generated by create-next-app

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that is for, but there is a thing called `bubbling` and it is triggered for example when you have a clickable element inside another clickable element.

something like

```
<div class="item1" onclick="do1()">
    <div class="item2" onclick="do2()">
        <div class="item3" onclick="do3()">
    </div>
</div>
```

So when you click on `item3` it will execute `do3()` first, but then it will also execute `do2()` and `do1()` as long as you dont disable it.

So this is called `bubbling`, it goes up from child to parent and the `bubble root` is `item1` (in this case).

Opposite effect is called `capturing`